# SpringSecurity password validation (special chars in passwords)

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I've cracked my head recently trying to find the way to *ALLOW* special characters for passwords in spring-security-core grails plugin.
Anyone could gimme the hint where to look at?

Clarification: when I install spring-security-core, spring-security-ui grails plugins and trying to register user supplying simple password consist of [\w\d]{,8} I'm getting the error:
`Password must have at least one letter, number, and special character: !@#$%^&`

Comment: Could you clarify? There's no restriction on password in the core plugin, other than the suggested constraints in the generated User class, which you're free to edit.

Comment: the restriction comes from the register command object, which contains a password validator constraints. change the contraint like you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar issue created: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYUI-25
Better solution would be:

```
class RegisterController extends grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.RegisterController {
def index = {
    [command: new RegisterCommand()]
}

static final myPasswordValidator = { String password, command ->
        if (command.username && command.username.equals(password)) {
        return 'command.password.error.username'
    }

    if (password && password.length() >= 8 && password.length() <= 64 &&
            (!password.matches('^.*\\p{Alpha}.*$') ||
                 !password.matches('^.*\\p{Digit}.*$')
             )) {
        return 'command.password.error.strength'
    }
}
 }

      class RegisterCommand {

String username
String email
String password
String password2

static constraints = {
    username blank: false, validator: { value, command ->
    if (value) {
    def User = AH.application.getDomainClass(
                                                     SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.userDomainClassName).clazz
            if (User.findByUsername(value)) {
                return 'registerCommand.username.unique'
            }
        }
}
    email blank: false, email: true, validator: { value, command ->                                                                                                                                                                                                          
            if (value) {
            def User = AH.application.getDomainClass(
                                                     SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.userLookup.userDomainClassName).clazz
            if (User.findByEmail(value)) {
                return 'registerCommand.email.unique'
    }
        }    
}
    password blank: false, minSize: 8, maxSize: 64, validator: RegisterController.myPasswordValidator
password2 validator: RegisterController.password2Validator
}
}



class ResetPasswordCommand {
String username
String password
String password2

static constraints = {
password blank: false, minSize: 8, maxSize: 64, validator: RegisterController.myPasswordValidator
password2 validator: RegisterController.password2Validator
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, Apart form defining a custom validator, why is this a better solution? Thanks, Jim.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should create your own RegisterController extending the Spring Security UI one as documented here: http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/guide/10%20Customization.html

```
grails s2ui-override Register com.my.package
```

and then override the passwordValidator method replacing the validation method with what you want:

```
if (password && password.length() >= 8 && password.length() <= 64 &&
    (!password.matches('^.*\\p{Alpha}.*$') ||
    !password.matches('^.*\\p{Digit}.*$') || {
    return 'command.password.error.strength'
}
```

If you don't want special characters to be forced in the password(?!)

Jim.

Answer (score 1):

what about doing something like this?

add this to your Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.password.validationRegex='^([a-zA-Z0-9@*#_%])$'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.password.minLength=8
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.password.maxLength=64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the parameters in the config.groovy.  These will overwrite the default parameters. So for example:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.password.validationRegex='^([a-zA-Z0-9@*#_%])*$'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.password.minLength=8
grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.password.maxLength=64
```

This is similar to the answer Jeff provided earlier however, in his qnswer, there is an asterix missing which implies it will only match a one character string.

(I cannot add this as a comment as I do not have sufficient reputation)